# Spark Streaming k-means with data from remote SQL server

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Stream is expected from a text file:

```
val trainingData = ssc.textFileStream("/training/data/dir").map(Vectors.parse)
val testData = ssc.textFileStream("/testing/data/dir").map(LabeledPoint.parse)
```

I need to read data from a remote MySQL server. Are there options other than updating the data file according to changes in SQL table?